# Redirect to custom page from site menu option

Tags: wordpress

On my site, I have a menu option called 'Data Entry'. When the user clicks on this, a custom WordPress login screen will open. When the user successfully logs in, he should be redirected to a data entry page.

How do I achieve the redirection after the user logs in? I have already created the custom login screen. Just need to know how to go about redirecting the user to the data entry page.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom template and have the following conditions:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
   // your code for logged in user 
} else {
   // your code for when user is not logged in 
}
```

You can also use the `wp_redirect()` function to [redirect to specific page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/).